# Detect outlier value in array of strings - VanillaJS & parseInt

Tags: javascript, parseint

Given a string of even and odd numbers, find which is the sole even number or the sole odd number.

Examples :
detectOutlierValue("2 4 7 8 10"); // => 2 - Third number is odd, while the rest of the numbers are even

Why do I need to parseInt(evens) again even though I have already converted everything into numbers?

```
function detectOutlierValue(str) {
  //array of strings into array of numbers
  newArr = str.split(" ").map(x => parseInt(x))

  evens = newArr.filter(num => num % 2 === 0)
  odds = newArr.filter(num => num % 2 !== 0)

  //if the array of evens has just 1 item while the majority is odds, we want to return the position of that item from the original string.

  if (evens.length === 1) {
    return newArr.indexOf(parseInt(evens)) 
  } else {
    return newArr.indexOf(parseInt(odds)) 
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you do...if I `console.log( typeof evens[0] );`, I get `number`...

Comment: Never mind, I see what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

It's because `evens` and `odds` are arrays at the time you put them into `indexOf`. Try replacing the last two lines with the first value of each array:

```
function detectOutlierValue(str) {
  //array of strings into array of numbers
  newArr = str.split(" ").map(x => parseInt(x))

  evens = newArr.filter(num => num % 2 === 0)
  odds = newArr.filter(num => num % 2 !== 0)

  //if the array of evens has just 1 item while the majority is odds, we want to return the position of that item from the original string.

  if (evens.length === 1) {
    return newArr.indexOf(evens[0]) 
  } else {
    return newArr.indexOf(odds[0]) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `evens` and `odds` are not `numbers`.They are `arrays`. In this case `odds = [7]`.So you `parseInt([7])` to get `7`.See the odds in console. You return `odds[0]` and `evens[0]`

```js
function detectOutlierValue(str) {
  //array of strings into array of numbers
  newArr = str.split(" ").map(x => parseInt(x))

  evens = newArr.filter(num => num % 2 === 0)
  odds = newArr.filter(num => num % 2 !== 0)
  //if the array of evens has just 1 item while the majority is odds, we want to return the position of that item from the original string.

  if (evens.length === 1) {
    return newArr.indexOf(evens[0]) 
  } else {
    console.log("odds =",odds);
    return newArr.indexOf(odds[0]) 
  }
}
console.log(detectOutlierValue("2 4 7 8 10"))
```